# Migrating database from Sql server to mySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, schema

I have a product called document management system and we are using Sql-server for storing user data for the same,

now one of our client wanted us to migrate the database from sql-server to mySql and when we tried to migrate the same the schema of our sql-server i.e

```
Access
Master
Dbo
Workflow
Report
```

are getting converted into separate databases for example,

We have a database in Sql-Server called `DocPro` with the above schemas which is getting converted into the following databases in  MySql

`DocPro`
`Access`
`Master`
`Dbo`
`Workflow`
`Report`

is there any way to create schemas instead of databases? or is it even possible?

Comment: isn't schema = database in mysql?

Comment: yes it's database in mySql but what is schema in mySql?

Comment: it's database LOL. you can just think of them as same thing

Comment: Ok, can you give me any suggestion, how can I migrate now?

Comment: As in my sql server I have a table structure like (schema name->table name), And I want to do the same in MySql

Comment: for example access.users

Comment: from what i understand, it will work automatically, you can try running select * from Access.users in mysql?

Comment: Yes I understood, but it will be a different database.

Comment: yes, since you can't have many schemas in same database in MySQL

Comment: This is a naive question. MySQL is not just another version of SQL-Server. If you can't handle even the schema/database issue, how are you going to cope with the language and syntax differences, and the requirement for different drivers in your application code?

Comment: In MySQL, a schema is synonymous with a database. You can substitute the keyword SCHEMA instead of DATABASE in MySQL SQL syntax, for example using CREATE SCHEMA instead of CREATE DATABASE. So, it is not possible to create schemas within a database in MySQL like you can in SQL Server. Instead, each schema in SQL Server would be migrated as a separate database in MySQL.